# What is the expectation of exponential of the product of two random variables?

Tags: distributions, variance, moments, exponential-distribution, moment-generating-function

I am looking for examples of probability distributions that would allow me to characterize the distribution (at least approximately) and to compute the first two moments exactly of:

$$
e^{aXY}
$$

where $a$ is a positive real and $X$ and $Y$ are scalar random variables defined on the positive real line and jointly distributed with mean/variance $(\mu_{X},\sigma^2_{X})$ and $(\mu_{Y},\sigma^2_{Y})$ and covariance $\sigma_{XY}$.

Any suggestions very welcome. I'm looking for examples, so hopefully there should be more than one approach to this.

Comment: I'm not tied to the lognormal distribution, it's just an example that came to mind... Is the exponential-exponential of a normal a base-e-squared lognormal? (or is this last sentence total nonsense)

Comment: Did you try using http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function ?

Comment: Thanks Stat-R. I don't know an awful lot about stats. I have looked at the mgf page. If I understand, it's about expressions of the form $e^{tX}$, where $X$ is a random vector but $t$ is deterministic, so in effect it's an exponential of a sum of rvs, as opposed to an exponential of products. So not sure how to proceed from there...

Comment: Thanks Macro. I'm only looking for examples where the distribution of $e^{aXY}$ can be characterized, at least approximately, and the first two moments computed explicitly. I have no assumption about $X$ and $Y$, except that they are positive and continuous (not discrete, I forgot to insist on that). 

I wrote down the first moment when $X$ and $Y$ are LogNormal, but it's messy. But that doesn't mean it can't be solved: writing out the expected value of the Normal is very messy too, until you know what changes of variable to apply.

Comment: @PatrickT: The mgf of a lognormal does not exist for any positive $t$.

Comment: Thanks cardinal, I think I now understand what that means!

Comment: I have deleted this paragraph, because it seems that I was on the wrong track there. I am copying it here so that the comments that pertained to that paragraph may be understood:    

"For instance, the product $Z=XY$ of two dependent lognormal variables is also lognormal, if I'm not mistaken, and presumably multiplying by a positive number wouldn't change that, but what about the distribution of the exponential of a lognormal? Now that would be the exponential of the exponential of a normal... what do we know about that distribution?"

Answer (score 1):

I'm entering this as an "answer" to my own question even though it's probably not much of an answer. But hopefully this will help in showing what I'm after. I will edit it or delete it if asked. Edit: This is still work in progress. I should probably mention that Stat-R, cardinal, StasK, and Macro have guided me every step of the way to ... where I have stopped now. Please do feel free to edit/correct this draft.

I'm looking for examples of a joint distributions of the dependent rvs $X$ and $Y$ such that (1) the distribution can be characterized, at least approximately, (2) the following can be computed exactly:
$$ 
E[e^{aXY}] 
$$

Example 1. Let:
$$ 
X = x + \epsilon 
$$
$$ 
Y = y + \epsilon 
$$
$$ 
\epsilon \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^{2}) 
$$
where $x$ and $y$ are fixed real numbers (the known means of $X$ and $Y$).

Remark: 
$$ 
e^{\epsilon} \sim \mathcal{LN}(0,\sigma^{2})
$$
$$
E[e^{\epsilon}]=e^{\sigma^{2}/2}
$$
It follows from a substitution of $x+\epsilon$ and $y+\epsilon$ into $XY$ that:
$$ 
E[e^{aXY}] = e^{axy} \times E[e^{a(x+y)\epsilon} e^{a\epsilon^{2}}] 
$$

Edit: The $\epsilon^{2}$ is not negligeable, as explained in the comments. Thus,

$$ E[e^{aXY}] = e^{axy} \times E[e^{a(x+y)\epsilon}] \times E[e^{a\epsilon^{2}}] + e^{2axy} \times COV[e^{a(x+y)\epsilon},e^{a\epsilon^{2}}]
$$

The first expectation on the rhs:
$$
E[e^{a(x+y)\epsilon}] = e^{a^{2}(x+y)^{2}\sigma^{2}/2} 
$$

The second expectation on the rhs features the square of a Normal, which is a Chi-squared. Edit: I have been shown, in the comments, how to compute the expectation by exploiting the fact that it's an evaluation of the MGF of a chi-squared, since $(\epsilon/\sigma)^{2}\sim\chi_{1}^{2}$. Therefore, 
$$
E[e^{a\epsilon^{2}}] = (1-2a/\sigma^{2})^{-k/2} = 1/\sqrt{1-2a/\sigma^{2}}, \ a < \sigma^{2}/2
$$
where $k$ denotes the degrees of freedom, which in this case is $k=1$, as the chi-squared is obtained from $1$ squared Normal. If $a>\sigma^{2}/2$, then the expectation diverges.

Lastly, the covariance term. I think here I need to compute this from the integral, hopefully some known results can be used along the way. If someone knows how to finish this it would be great, but I'm stuck.

Comment: I have neglected the covariance between $e^{a(x+y)\epsilon}$ and $e^{a\epsilon^{2}}$, which may not be a smart move...

Comment: ${\rm Prob}[\epsilon^2 > \epsilon] = {\rm Prob}[\epsilon^2 > 1] =$ 32%, which is not negligible.

Comment: Thanks StasK, yes that was a badly inspired simplification...

Comment: You should have edited your question with the information rather than put it out as an answer.

Comment: Re: **"Not sure how difficult it would be to compute the expectation of the exponential of a chi-square"**, you could use the moment generating function for that. From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution), if $X$ has a $\chi^2$ distribution with $k$ degrees of freedom, then $m_{X}(a) = E (e^{aX}) = (1 − 2a)^{−k/2}$ for $ a < 1/2 $. In general, it may help you to look at how various moment generating functions are derived to get a handle on some tricks for calculating $E(e^{aXY})$. Most theoretical statistics texts should have some examples.

Comment: @StasK, +1, but to be fair, when $\sigma$ is small, this term does become pretty negligible since if $\varepsilon \sim N(0,\sigma)$, then $P(\varepsilon^2 > 1) \propto \Phi(-1/\sigma)$.

Comment: @Macro, you're right, I missed the $\sigma$ in there.

Comment: Thanks guys for your follow-up. I understand now how the MGF can be a great tool in this instance. I'm guessing that the degrees of freedom is $k=2$ in this case, because of multiplying 2 Normals together. As for the covariance, it looks like a case of going through the steps of $E(X-E(X))(Y-E(Y))$. I haven't time to do that now, it's the middle of the night here... To be continued...

Comment: @PatrickT, regarding your remark above **"in this case is $k=2$, as the chi-squared is obtained by multiplying 2 standard Normal together"** this isn't quite right - the $\chi^2$ distribution arises as the sum of the squares of iid standard normal random variables and the degrees of freedom are actually equal to the number of terms in the sum which, in this case, is 1. Also I made an error earlier: since $\epsilon$ is not necessarily _standard_ normal, its square follows a [non-central $\chi^2$ distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_chi-squared_distribution), not $\chi^2$.

Comment: Thanks Macro, I'm going to read up on that and attempt to fix the errors! Thanks a lot.

Comment: @PatrickT, thinking about this again, the non-central $\chi^2$ distribution involves each term in the sum being scaled by its standard deviation, so $\varepsilon^2$ can't be non-central $\chi^2$ distributed. But, since $\epsilon$ does have mean 0, $\varepsilon^2 = \frac{1}{\sigma^2} \cdot (\frac{\varepsilon}{\sigma})^2$. From there $(\frac{\varepsilon}{\sigma})^2 \sim \chi^{2}_{1}$ since it is the square of a standard normal. Therefore $\varepsilon^2$ s a scalar multiple of a $\chi^2_1$ random variable - sorry for my sloppiness in the previous comment(s).

Comment: Based on my last comment, I think you're missing a multiple of $1/\sigma^2$ in your last line - shouldn't it be $1/\sqrt{1-2a/\sigma^2}$?

Comment: Thanks a lot Macro. I have fixed the errors, I hope. I'm terribly sorry for leaving this aside for a few days. I'll try to make some headway some time next week after I get these other things done. Thanks.

Comment: I reviewed a suggested edit on this post. PatrickT, did you forget your login? In this case, please flag this post for moderator attention and we'll make the necessary.

Comment: Thanks chl. Something strange happened to my account indeed, I suddenly got it back today, unexpectedly and I don't know how. I'm okay with any edit you have, go ahead. As you can see I've not been able to finish my answer, got stuck somewhere and moved on. I still think the question is good, but it's in need of an answer for sure...

Comment: Be careful, this answer contains a mistake. It states that $$
E(e^{a\epsilon^{2}}) = (1-2a/\sigma^{2})^{-k/2} = 1/\sqrt{1-2a/\sigma^{2}}, \ a < \sigma^{2}/2
$$ Let's start with the first comment from Macro. As he points out, it's true that if $X \sim \chi_{k}^{2}$ then $$
E (e^{aX}) = (1 − 2a)^{−k/2}
$$ Which for $z \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ means $$
E (e^{az^{2}}) = (1 − 2a)^{−1/2}
$$ And for $\epsilon \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^{2})$ this means

$$
E (e^{a\epsilon^{2}}) = E (e^{a\sigma^{2}z^{2}}) = (1 − 2a\sigma^{2})^{−1/2}  = 1/\sqrt{1-2a\sigma^{2}}, \ a < \frac{1}{2\sigma^{2}}
$$

Comment: Thanks Javier! If you know how to put together an answer, I'll delete mine and accept yours, and bring a bit of closure to whatever this was. :-)